# App Crashes , but no device log

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I swipe the tableview, and it would crashes, I try to find device console under windows, devices in Xcode, but there's no log.
If I use XCode to run the app. It crash without telling me why. But just lost the connection with my phone.[image]

Comment: It's a memory issue. Debug and check memory issues and fix it.

Comment: Did you try a simulator?

Comment: @Wolverine I guess so.Do you mean I should use leaks to find the problem?

Comment: Its happen Sometime because your connection getting lose to your device. Reconnect device wait to complete attaching process then clean & run.

Comment: Read this link : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-visual-memory-debugger/

Answer (score 1):

**One cause for those searcing on the question in the title:**

This problem can occur if you have a bad iOS cable connected. The cable could work perfectly normal but in some angles when twisted and turned , could fail and lose connection.

**Second cause (Your cause):**

> I swipe the tableview

Something in your tableView is not set up correctly. Probably as mentioned in the comment section below your question, memory issues. Add code to your question for us to be able to check even further in detail.

Comment: I was bout to say the same, loosing connection is only due to bad cable xD

Comment: Well. I believe so. But if I don't connect to the XCode, the app crashes the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's a memory issue. The system kills the app while it's going to load to many images. I commented the code "decodedImageWithImage" in SDWebImage, And the problem got fixed.